# Skipping first argv in DLang array

Tags: d

I am starting to learn D. I wrote a few basic programs (hello world... add 2 numbners) and I'm on to my third. It should take an array of numbers and add them  together. I have the following code:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;
import std.string;
import std.conv;

int main(string[] argv)
{
    int sum;
    foreach (int i, string s; argv) 
    {
        writefln("argv[%d] = '%s'", i, s);
        if (isNumeric(s)){
            sum += to!int(s);
        } else {
            writeln("Please only input numbers. ex:\n\t", argv[0], " [number] [number] [number]");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    writeln(sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue I am having is that `argv[0]` is the script name.

1. Why?
2. How do I tell it to skip the first one? I could just tell it to skip all non-numeric inputs, but maybe I'd want to error out if the index is greater than 0?

Comment: 1) because it is, 2) `if (i == 0) continue;`

Comment: Is there a convention of why it is?

Comment: You should take a look at [std.getopt](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_getopt.html). It is a part of the standard library that makes parsing command line arguments much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`argv[0]` is always the name by which the program was called, it is part of the C standard that D inherited. It is useful if you have a single program that can be called by multiple names on the command line - it helps you know what the user wanted as one program might be several commands (see the C program `busybox` for a big example of that, the one program contains several common unix commands). You can also use it for the help screen, like you did.

The reason it is part of args is that the command line is like: `program foo bar` - the program name is the first thing given on that line, so it is the first thing in args too.

But to skip it, you can just slice it off before the loop:

```
foreach (int i, string s; argv)
```

Can become

```
foreach (int i, string s; argv[1 .. $])
```

Though, then i will be offset too - i == 0 when argv == 1, so you might want to just say `if(i == 0) continue;` in the loop as well to skip it.

Comment: I decided not to slice it so I could print the program name in output if they do it wrong. But I thought about this.

Comment: If you slice right in the loop, you can still access the full thing from outside - with my foreach line, `argv[0]` still refers to the program name, it just isn't included in the `int i, string s` loop.

Comment: Oh. Neat. I'll try that. Thanks. That is probably better than making an index comparison every time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer... Not sure if it's the best way:

Just check if the index is greater than 0:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;
import std.string;
import std.conv;

int main(string[] argv)
{
    if (argv.length <= 2){
        writeln("Type numbers after the script to add them together. ex:\n\t", argv[0], " [number] [number] [number]");
        return 0;
    } else {
        int sum;
        foreach (int i, string s; argv) 
        {

            if (i > 0) // skip the first argv. it is the script name.
            {
                if (isNumeric(s)){
                    sum += to!int(s);
                } else {
                    writeln("Please only input numbers. ex:\n\t", argv[0], " [number] [number] [number]");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        writeln(sum);
        return 0;
    }
}
```